Flipping train and test labels for binary classification
I was training a GCN (this one) on a single graph (n=1,1304 nodes, num_features=26) to perform node level binary classification. However, my model performed with 5% accuracy (and even went as low to 0% for some random seeds).
I thought that this figure was too low, even if the model didn't recognize any patterns in my data.  So I flipped all my train and test labels (turned the 0s into 1s and vice versa). I then re-trained and re-tested my model on the flipped label data and it performed much better, with 93.8% accuracy. I was wondering if anyone had any insight into why this may be, and if flipping labels before training is a standard in some cases.
I looked at some other answers on the Artificial Intelligence stack exchange, but I think they all talked about training on un-flipped labels then flipping only the test labels. However, I'm flipping both train and test labels. If I'm doing something to bias the results of my model, then please tell me.
Thank you.

Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65131391/what-exactly-is-kerass-categoricalcrossentropy-doing
Your problem might be related to it (or it just might be a bug in your code...).
